# Union and intersection of Dedekind Cuts

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am confused about the proof of following claim:

Let A and B be dedekind cuts. How can we show that A is subset of B (including equality possibility) $\Longrightarrow$ $A \cup B = B$? and similarly A is subset of B (including equality possibility) $\Longrightarrow$ $A \cap B = A$?

Comment: $A\subseteq B\implies A\cup B=B$ and $A\subseteq B\implies A\cap B=A$ are true for all sets. Just use the definitions of subset, union, intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Dedekind Cuts are just ordinary sets (or pairs of sets, depending on your notation). So, here $A,\ B$ are just two sets. Now, $ A \subset B$ means that any element that is contained in $A$ is also contained in $B$, and so 'union-ing' $A$ with $B$ does not contribute any new element that was not already in $B$. That is, $A \cup B = B$.